# Angular custom filter doesnt work on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am learning Angular so I created casual To do app. Custom filter works on localhost while on hosting it doesnt. I don't get any error messages and data doesn't show. If i remove `taskPriority:this` from `li` data shows which means on the server everything is ok but then, of course, filtering doesn't work. I am passing scope (this) to filter.

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | taskPriority:this | filter:taskname as ukupno track by $index">
    <input class="edit_task" ng-blur="editTask(task.id, task.task)" ng-model="task.task" value="{{ task.task }}" type="text">
</li>
```

Filter checks if there is priority level (1,2,3) in array fSPriorites matching priority in task, if yes then it returns those tasks.

```
angular.module('TaskFilter', []).filter('taskPriority', function() {
    return function(task, scope) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(task, function(task) {
            if($.inArray(task.priority, scope.fSPriorites) != -1)
                filtered.push(task);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

How do i debug this?

Comment: try  changing `<li ng-repeat="task in ukupno = (tasks | taskPriority:this | filter:taskname) track by $index">`

Comment: unfortunately, no results on hosting server although its working allright on local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are passing scope to fileter. This is not a good practice. Try below code.

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | taskPriority:this.fSPriorites | filter:taskname as ukupno track by $index">
    <input class="edit_task" ng-blur="editTask(task.id, task.task)" ng-model="task.task" value="{{ task.task }}" type="text">
</li>
```

**Filter**

```
angular.module('TaskFilter', []).filter('taskPriority', function() {
    return function(task, fSPriorites) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(task, function(task) {
            if($.inArray(task.priority, fSPriorites) != -1)
                filtered.push(task);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Hope this could help you.Thanks,

Comment: It still doesnt work. i get no data http://angular-laravel.wc.lt/#/tasks but if I remove call to custom filter from li tag it works. http://postimg.org/image/gqj7ouck7/ Really strange, but I'm doing this just for practice so it isn't a big deal. thank you for your time

Comment: @Marko may be response is wrong on server..or something bad happen with `fSPriorites` variable of scope. it may be `null` or `undefined`..that may causing `if($.inArray(task.priority, fSPriorites) != -1)` to false and no records gets filtered

Comment: the problem was that for some reason inArray (and indexOf which I also tried to use) didn't work properly. finally its working with for each loop. ty

Comment: In addition $.inArray will never work in IE8..Thats cool fix..Feeling glad to help you.